# Copy rows from a range if a string matches on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I'm trying to copy only the rows (not the entire row) from range `E3:H` until the end from the sheet `test1` using the column `H:H` as parameter to check if a string matches on sheet `test2` at the cell `D1`

For example.: If in sheet `test2` the value of the cell `D1` is `dog`, it must copy all the rows from the range `C3:H` of the `sheet1` using the column `H3:H` of the `sheet1` as parameter (if dog exists in some rows). So it should copy the matched rows for the sheet `test2` in the column `M3`

Well, it's being hard for me. Someone can help?

Thank you

```
   Sub Test()
    Dim rw As Long, Cell As Range
    LastRow = Sheets("test1").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For Each Cell In Sheets("test1").Range("H:H")
    rw = Cell.Row
     If Cell.Value = "D1" Then 'How do i define to take the value `D1` from sheet `test2`?
      Cell.Range("E3:H" & LastRow).Copy
       Sheets("test2").Range("M3:M" & LastRow & rw).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
     End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work, have a test let me know how you get on with it

*note: there are more efficient ways of doing this but hopefully this is easier to follow and should be plenty fast enough*

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rw As Long, rng As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
    LastRow = ws.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dog = Sheets("test2").Range("D1").Value
    i = 3
    
    For Each rng In ws.Range("H3:H" & LastRow)
        rw = rng.Row
        If rng.Value = Dog Then
            Sheets("test2").Range("M" & i & ":R" & i).Value = ws.Range("C" & rw & ":H" & rw).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why you specify range with something like "H3:H" ? And how does it translate to actual cells ?

Comment: So h3 is cell h3.  The ":" allows you to define a range.  Hence h3:h20 would be all the cells h3 to h20, so h3, h4, h5 etc.

Comment: I just noticed "& LastRow" right now which would get the last row number and add it to the "H" to be something like H3:H23 or whatever the last row is, sorry for the inconvenience :).

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Rows

- This is a basic code. *Copying by assignment* (`drrg.Value = srrg.Value`) instead of using `PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` is the only implementation to increase efficiency.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRows()
    
    ' 1. Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' 2. Source
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet ('sws').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Test1")
    ' Calculate the source last row ('slRow'),
    ' the row of the last non-empty cell in the column.
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Reference the source columns range ('scrg') whose rows will be copied.
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = sws.Columns("E:H")
    
    ' 3. Destination
    
    ' Reference the destination worksheet ('dws').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Test2")
    ' Reference the first destination row range by resizing the first
    ' destination cell by the number of columns of the source columns range.
    Dim drrg As Range: Set drrg = dws.Range("M3").Resize(, scrg.Columns.Count)
    ' Write the lookup string value to a string variable ('dlString').
    Dim dlString As String: dlString = CStr(dws.Range("D1").Value)
    
    ' 4. The Loop
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim srrg As Range ' Current Source Row Range
    Dim sr As Long ' Current Row in the Source Worksheet
    Dim slString As String ' Current String Lookup String
    
    ' Loop through the designated rows of the source worksheet.
    For sr = 3 To slRow
        ' Write the source string value in the current row to a variable.
        slString = CStr(sws.Cells(sr, "H").Value)
        ' Compare the string in the current row against the lookup string.
        ' The comparison is case-insensitive i.e. 'dog = DOG'
        ' due to the 'vbTextCompare' parameter.
        If StrComp(slString, dlString, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' is equal
            ' Reference the source row range.
            Set srrg = scrg.Rows(sr)
            ' Write the values from the source row range
            ' to the destination row range ('copy by assignment').
            drrg.Value = srrg.Value
            ' Reference the next destination row range (one row below).
            Set drrg = drrg.Offset(1)
        'Else ' is not equal; do nothing
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' 5. Inform to not wonder if the code has run or not.
    MsgBox "Rows copied.", vbInformation
        
End Sub
```