# Copy data from one sheet as new row under the corresponding category in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, finance

I am quite familiar with Excel, but new to VBA and would love any assistance that could be provided. I did [post on Mr Excel](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-copy-data-as-new-row-under-the-corresponding-category.1227092/#post-6004036) but haven't gotten any assistance, so I thought I would try my hand here.

I am wanting to automate my monthly financial tracker. I currently download my account activity on a routine basis, manually categorize it, and then cut it into categorized sections so I can track the amount spent for each category. It seems like I could potentially download my account activity, still manually categorize it, and then have VBA run to copy the categorized data from one tab into another (as a new row).

> Sheet4 = Where I would paste Account Activity data (manually remove duplicates and categorize)
>
> Sheet3 = Where I want VBA to paste new rows of data (probably to the top of the corresponding section)
>
> Example: Hulu charge is categorized in Sheet4, column D as "TV Streaming", so data from columns A-C would be pasted under the TV Streaming section of Sheet 3 as new rows. So eventually these categories would be quite large.

I did leverage some code I found online [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72842691/copy-rows-from-a-range-if-a-string-matches-on-another-sheet), and it ALMOST does what I want but I have two things remaining.

1. It's only searching for the Rx/Dr category, probably because I specified cell "A2" in Line 19 (Sheet3). **Is there a way for that to be a variable search for any category in column A?**
2. The rows copied over in the order I wanted (oldest to newest), but they didn't insert themselves as a new row so they pasted into other categories. **What can I add to the code that would tell it to insert the copied cells and not just paste them?**

```
Sub CopyRows()
    
    ' 1. Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' 2. Source
     ' Calculate the source last row ('slRow'),
    ' the row of the last non-empty cell in the column.
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = Sheet4.Cells(Sheet4.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Reference the source columns range ('scrg') whose rows will be copied.
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = Sheet4.Columns("A:C")
    
    ' 3. Destination
    
    ' Reference the first destination row range by resizing the first
    ' destination cell by the number of columns of the source columns range.
    Dim drrg As Range: Set drrg = Sheet3.Range("B3").Resize(, scrg.Columns.Count)
    ' Write the lookup string value to a string variable ('dlString').
    Dim dlString As String: dlString = CStr(Sheet3.Range("A2").Value)
    
    ' 4. The Loop
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim srrg As Range ' Current Source Row Range
    Dim sr As Long ' Current Row in the Source Worksheet
    Dim slString As String ' Current String Lookup String
    
    ' Loop through the designated rows of the source worksheet.
    For sr = 3 To slRow
        ' Write the source string value in the current row to a variable.
        slString = CStr(Sheet4.Cells(sr, "D").Value)
        ' Compare the string in the current row against the lookup string.
        ' The comparison is case-insensitive i.e. 'dog = DOG'
        ' due to the 'vbTextCompare' parameter.
        If StrComp(slString, dlString, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' is equal
            ' Reference the source row range.
            Set srrg = scrg.Rows(sr)
            ' Write the values from the source row range
            ' to the destination row range ('copy by assignment').
            drrg.Value = srrg.Value
            ' Reference the next destination row range (one row below).
            Set drrg = drrg.Offset(1)
            'Else ' is not equal; do nothing
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' 5. Inform to not wonder if the code has run or not.
    MsgBox "Rows copied.", vbInformation
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To find the first row in which the category is found:

   `Dim CategoryRow as Range`

   `Set CategoryRow = Sheet3.Range("A:A").Find(value).EntireRow`
2. `CategoryRow.Entirerow.Insert`

You might also want to consider looking into using Listobjects (Tables). Much more useful for a variety of reasons.

Still can't figure out how to post "code."

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply!

Would you be willing to explain how I could incorporate your answer(s) into my existing code? Although I will be attempting it myself, I am quite inexperienced and figure it wouldn't hurt to ask where you think these new lines should be added.

Comment: I'm not going to write the code for you.

Think about it. In the loop you are running through each row of your source data and looking for a place to put it in the destination. Your code says that the category is assigned variable slString. That is the "value" you are looking for in the destination sheet. The row that is found is where you want to insert a row and then paste your data into that row.

You might want to review which columns you are using though. slString is coming from column D. Are you sure you want to search column A for the category?

Comment: My apologies, I did not intend for you to re-write it for me. I am just not fully understanding where to place your suggestions - specifically inside or outside of the loop. 

Sheet4 (slString) is essentially downloaded account activity and I manually tack on the category on the final column (D); whereas on Sheet4 (dlString) has the category on the top-left (A) to make it more visible. I certainly appreciate your assistance and explanations thus far, it has been extremely helpful.